# Using HoldFirst but not wishing to hold everything

Tags: programming, function-construction

I have a DynamicModule in which I go through some data analysis and keep or reject the results. Here is a toy example of what I am doing.

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[{ip_, op_}] := DynamicModule[{a, b},
   a = ip;
   Column[{
      Dynamic[b = Total[a]],
      Row[{
       Button["keep", AppendTo[op, {ToString[Unevaluated[ip]], b}]],
       Button["reject", AppendTo[op, {ToString[Unevaluated[ip]], Null}]]
      }]
  }]
]
```

I make 10 sets of data

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {10}];
```

I now run my module on the first set using

```
op = {};
f[{data[[1]], op}]
```

Which gives me

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I look at my output I have

```
op
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is what I want. This output records the data set and the result.
If I do this again with all the data using a table I can still proceed

```
op = {};
Column[Table[f[{data[[n]], op}], {n, Length[data]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I press my buttons. However when I now look at my output all the records are data[[n]], data[[n]], data[[n]]... instead of data[[1]], data[[2]], data[[3]]...

```
op // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What I want is this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I make the n in the output of data[[n]] change to reflect the  input number? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `With` can inject into held expressions: `Column[Table[With[{n = n}, f[{data[[n]], op}]], {n, Length[data]}]]`

Comment: @Kuba A good workaround. Many thanks. Pity I can't include this in the module somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kuba suggested in his comment, [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) is helpful for accomplishing what you ask for.

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[ip_] :=
  Module[{b},
    Column[{b = Total[ip], 
      Row[{
        Button["keep", AppendTo[op, {ToString[Unevaluated[ip]], b}]],
        Button["reject", AppendTo[op, {ToString[Unevaluated[ip]], Null}]]}]}]]

SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 10}];
op = {};
Column[Table[With[{n = n}, f[data[[n]]]], {n, Length[data]}]]
```

[image: output]

```
op
```

> ```
> {
>   {"data[[1]]", -1.47076}, 
>   {"data[[2]]", Null}, 
>   {"data[[3]]", 3.35806}, 
>   {"data[[4]]", 2.33047}
> }
> ```

To reduce the size of my answer, I have reduced the data to four lists of ten real numbers and omitted the formatting of the output. I have also done some simplification on your definition of `f`. In particular, I eliminated the use of dynamic constructs as they are not needed for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this solves my problem although it makes using the module more complicated. The simplifications to my module are also worth considering. This could leave to another question...